# How do I implement Sha512 in my web application>?

Tags: web-applications, sha512

I want to implement `sha512` in my web application, so the passwords on my database can't be  visible.Does anybody how to write the code to achieve this? Any help is greatly Appreciated!

Comment: It would be useful to know what language your are writing your web application in!

Comment: To clarify this should be done serverside, almost every language has some kind of library(standard or third part) for handling issues like this

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$hashed = crypt("secret", '$6$xxxxxxxx$');
```

Java:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.Crypt;
String hashed = Crypt.crypt("secret", "$6$xxxxxxxx$");
```

It's important that you always use a "Salt" when encrypting passwords and not just save the output of sha512("secret") to make "rainbow table" attacks harder. The "xxxxxxx" above should be replaced by a random string from the character set a–zA–Z0–9./

Answer (score 0):

you can include the sha512 algorithm as a javascript file in your web page like this,

```
 <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha512.js">         </script>
 <script>
  var hash = CryptoJS.SHA512("Message");
 </script>
```

for more information view the pages:

https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/
  https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn-history/r491/branches/3.x/src/sha512.js